# Building SDL2 for iOS with Xcode 7

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opengl-es, sdl-2

I am trying to build SDL2 for iOS with Xcode7. I am using the provided project and getting lots of OpenGL ES related errors

```
SDL_video.c:2462:11: error: unknown type name 'GLubyte'
```

It seems that the build system is unable to find relevant OpenGL ES headers.